# Link to nested resource collection index page in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a `Category` model, which has many `Products`.

I would like to add a link in the `Category` index page that links to a prefiltered version of the product index. Something like:

```
link_to "View Products in This Category", admin_products(:product_id => self.id)
```

but can't seem to find any clear documentation on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_to "View Products in This Category", :controller => "products", :action => "index", 'q[product_category_id_eq]' => "#{p.id}".html_safe
```

Answer (score 8):

Id recommend doing it the restful way, activeadmin has this type of functionality built in since its built off inherited resources, which has a controller belongs_to method, e.g.

admin/categories.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do

  #assuming you have a category name field
  index do
    column "Name" do |category|
      link_to(category.name, admin_category_products_path(category)
    end

  end

end
```

admin/products.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  belongs_to :category

end
```

Answer (score 0):

And how about this :

```
link_to "View Products in This Category", admin_products(:category_id => category.id)
```

If you are in the category index page, you should have something like that in your view :

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.name %>
    ...
    <%= link_to "View Products in This Category", admin_products(:category_id => category.id) %>
<% end %>
```